# How To Access Controls in Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, include, code-behind

i have a page named Default.aspx and inside it i use an include virtual for the header. Is there a way i can use the controls inside that header in Default.aspx.cs? (Code Behind).It just doesn't recognize the code inside the include file, everytime i try to compile .net throws me a lot of errors related to unrecognized controls..

I know i can put my header inside the default page  as usual, but i'd like to keep it in a separate file because it has a lot of content.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Post some code please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you want to do that?

Only reason I can come up with is reusability - and that could be solved by using a masterpage containing the header information or a usercontrol (or even a custom control)

I'd probably go with the masterpage solution - but your description of what and why you want to do as you do is a lite vague...

Comment: Yeah, the main reason is for reusability, i don't want to have the same 100 lines of header in every page of my site instead of including the header where i need it.. Thanks.

Comment: Use a masterpage then. It gives you advantage of shared layout as well. You can even nest masterpages in masterpages.

Comment: So if you for example would want to include some javascripts in all of your pages, but only header in some pages. Then you could have a "base masterpage" (or master-master-page) if you like.

So if I were you I'd look into masterpages for inspiration. Because it looks like you're trying to do ASP in ASP.NET ;)

Comment: That's right, i really appreciate your help, thanks again :)